# gdal2tiles.py: Attempt to create 0x1249 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to convert some weather data into tiles so I can show it on a website. I am downloading the weather data from NOAA using their [grib filer](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/gribfilter.php?ds=gfs_0p25).

I download the file, convert to tiff, convert to 8bit tiff and then try and convert to tiles with the following commands:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f000 output.tif
gdal_translate -ot Byte output.tif output_8bit.tif
gdal2tiles.py --zoom=4-6 output_8bit.tif tiles
```

However I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempt to create 0x1249 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
```

How can I convert this grib file into tiles using gdal?

(for reference, the download url for the grib file I am using is https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?dir=%2Fgfs.20230614%2F00%2Fatmos&file=gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f000&var_UGRD=on&lev_10_m_above_ground=on however the url may become invalid if you view this question at a later date).

Also for reference, the full stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 15, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 4527, in main
    return submain(argv)
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 4544, in submain
    single_threaded_tiling(input_file, output_folder, options)
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 4385, in single_threaded_tiling
    conf, tile_details = worker_tile_details(input_file, output_folder, options)
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 4289, in worker_tile_details
    gdal2tiles.open_input()
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 2207, in open_input
    self.warped_input_dataset = reproject_dataset(
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 1102, in reproject_dataset
    return gdal.Warp(
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 788, in Warp
    return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)
  File "/home/tom/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 4815, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName
    return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
RuntimeError: Attempt to create 0x1249 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

This crash is because `gdal2tiles` requires the coordinates to be within -180/180 & 90/-90. Additionally you should also override the projection, since what GDAL picks up from the grib file is a bit exotic and doesn't play nice with `gdal2tiles`.

A quick fix can be to, at your first step, just discard the pixels outside that range. For example:

```py
gdal_translate -of GTiff -srcwin 1 1 1438 719 -a_srs EPSG:4326 gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f000 output.tif
```

That should at least make `gdal2tiles` run.

You should probably also scale/color the file differently but that's a separate issue unrelated to this question. The values in your data, as you use it now range from 0 to 32 (but most much lower). Visualizing that as 8bit (0 to 255) makes everything very dark/black.